# On finite separable morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, positive-characteristic, separable-extension

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a finite separable morphism of smooth projective varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $d$ be the degree of $f$. We have an exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_Y\longrightarrow f_\ast\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}\longrightarrow 0$$
When $\operatorname{char} k\nmid d$ the above exact sequence splits via $\frac{1}{d}Tr:f_\ast\mathcal{O}_X\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_Y$, hence $H^0(Y,\mathcal{F})=0$. Does the latter equality hold also in the case $\operatorname{char} k\mid d$? I'm particularly interested in the case of curves.

Comment: The answer is yes, I would say, by the direct summand conjecture which says that if you have an injective ring map $A\to B$ and you assume

1) that $A\to B$ is finite.
2) that $A$ and $B$ are Noetherian.
3) that $A$ is regular

then $A\to B$ has an $A$-module section. Of course, you probably need vastly less than this in your case. I’d look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.08882.pdf and in particular at the reference [HO1].

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment, but it seems to me that all the direct summand conjecture gives you is the local splitting of the above exact sequence. However, this is not enough to conclude that a splitting exists globally.

Comment: No, you’re totally correct, I was inappropriately ignoring the gluing needed by using the result affine locally. That said, it might be worth looking anyways since if the splitting is somehow ‘natural’ you might be able to glue (the splitting when $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ is just the trace map for example). Sorry I couldn’t be of more help!